# What is the meaning of もの in ものすごく?

Tags: meaning, prefixes

I don't understand the function of もの in the following sentence:

> 薬が**もの**すごく苦かったから、急いで飲み込んだ。

The sentence makes perfect sense if I omit もの altogether, and I am not sure what is its function in the sentence. Could it be a typo?

> 薬が<strike>もの</strike>すごく苦かったから、急いで飲み込んだ。

> The medicine was so bitter that I swallowed it swiftly.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42941/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research in the Internet, I found out that もの is not a standalone word in the sentence above, but instead it is part of the word ものすごく, which has the same meaning than すごく but with stronger intensity:

> このカボチャすごく大きい! This pumpkin is very big!

> あのカボチャものすごく巨大だ！That pumpkin is huge!

([source](https://hinative.com/ja/questions/965638))

Answer (score 0):

もの is not a standalone word, it combines with すごく as a whole.ものすごく is an adverb form of ものすごい(物凄い), meaning that たいへんな。すごい(too much, great)

Comment: Could you expand your answer please? I fail to see where it adds new information or value to the discussion.